# How can I get MintMenu running in KDE?

Tags: kde

I've used KDE for a while now and I'm not going back to gnome, but one thing that I really want is MintMenu instead of lancelot or kickoff, I know it is for gnome, but is there any way to get it running in KDE? The only other thing I'd settle for is a menu exactly like the one in windows 7 or vista, I want something identical to one of those.

Why was this downvoted? I though it was a perfectly valid question. Was I wrong?

Comment: What is "MintMenu"? Are you talking about [Cinnamon](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/)?

Comment: yeah, I was talking about the native cinnamon launcher

Comment: why did this get downvoted?

Comment: You got downvoted probably because your question is off-topic, as it's not about Ubuntu. Please use http://unix.stackexchange.com/ for non-Ubuntu related Linux questions.

Comment: I am sorry I made an uninformed question, but I do not see why someone would need to downvote instead of just flag the question as not really related. I thought it was related enough at the time of asking, but I guess I was wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the homerun menu with a kickoff/windows menu appearence.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install plasma-widget-homerun
sudo apt-get install plasma-widget-homerun-kicker
```

[image]

**Homerun 1.20 announcement**

http://blogs.kde.org/2014/01/29/homerun-120

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I really just found that I can install cinnamon for when I just want a really simple environment (one that I'm more used to from windows) and use kde for when I'm well rested :P